# Restrict root to su local accounts

Tags: root, access-control, account-restrictions

I know that root can modify any config file.

<del>As a best practice, I would like to disable the capacity for root to su on accounts which authenticates against NIS or Active Directory.</del>

As a best practice, I would like to allow root to su only on local accounts. *My* definition of a local account is any line with an id in /etc/passwd (because of the `+user::::::` for NIS access).

I guess it would involve modifying the pam config, but I'm not clear on the how.

Comment: Are you asking about _restricting root_ from doing certain things? Usually, root is not restricted from doing anything.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes. On some hosts, at least, we don't want root to be able to impersonate as "network users", i.e users coming from ldap/sssd

Comment: As root can't be restricted in the way you describe (being the super-user means operating without restrictions), I propose that your issue is mostly a _social_ problem. The people with root access would need to work with an agreed set of operational rules, one of which is not to impersonate a network user.